# Where to set tableView.rowHeight?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to figure out where to properly set tableView.rowHeight. Currently I have it in my ViewDidLoad method, but as I am using images it seems to be scaling the images up from the default.

E.g. my cell images are 55px squared. But if I set [self.tableView.rowHeight = 55.0]; in ViewDidLoad, they look a bit blurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make space for the table view separator line (that is 1px), so if your image height is 55px, your table row height needs to be 56px.